# Training deep learning model with sparse matrix for Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, sparse-matrix, attention-model

I have a list of data features with variable lengths:

```
X_train[0]:
<9x15466 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 115 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

X_train[1]:
<201x15466 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4430 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

I have tried adopting the custom sparse dataset class provided [here](https://gist.github.com/KyleOng/e70c80c49991613eaa8acc7c238576f5) for building such a dataloader:

```
class SparseDataset(torch.utils.data.dataset.Dataset):
    """
    Custom Dataset class for scipy sparse matrix
    """
    def __init__(self, data:Union[np.ndarray, coo_matrix, csr_matrix], 
                 targets:Union[np.ndarray, coo_matrix, csr_matrix], 
                 transform:bool = None):
        
        # Transform data coo_matrix to csr_matrix for indexing
        if type(data) == coo_matrix:
            self.data = data.tocsr()
        else:
            self.data = data
            
        # Transform targets coo_matrix to csr_matrix for indexing
        if type(targets) == coo_matrix:
            self.targets = targets.tocsr()
        else:
            self.targets = targets
        
        self.transform = transform # Can be removed

    def __getitem__(self, index:int):
        return self.data[index], self.targets[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    
def sparse_coo_to_tensor(coo:coo_matrix):
    """
    Transform scipy coo matrix to pytorch sparse tensor
    """
    values = coo.data
    indices = np.vstack((coo.row, coo.col))
    shape = coo.shape

    i = torch.LongTensor(indices)
    v = torch.FloatTensor(values)
    s = torch.Size(shape)

    return torch.sparse.FloatTensor(i, v, s)
    

def sparse_batch_collate(batch:list): 
    """
    Collate function which to transform scipy coo matrix to pytorch sparse tensor
    """
    data_batch, targets_batch = zip(*batch)
    if type(data_batch[0]) == csr_matrix:
        data_batch = vstack(data_batch).tocoo()
        data_batch = sparse_coo_to_tensor(data_batch)
    else:
        data_batch = torch.FloatTensor(data_batch)

    if type(targets_batch[0]) == csr_matrix:
        targets_batch = vstack(targets_batch).tocoo()
        targets_batch = sparse_coo_to_tensor(targets_batch)
    else:
        targets_batch = torch.FloatTensor(targets_batch)
        
    #Added padding here
    lengths = torch.tensor([ t.shape[0] for t in data_batch ])
    data_batch = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(data_batch)
    return data_batch, targets_batch
```

Why am I getting a TypeError for what this class is intended to do?

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=SparseDataset(X_train, y_train),
#                                            batch_sampler=batches,
                                           batch_size=100,
                                           shuffle=True,
                                           collate_fn=sparse_batch_collate)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26192/1278121171.py in 
> ----> 1 for a in enumerate(iter(train_loader)):
> 2     break
>
> D:\bo\envs\bd\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in
> **next**(self)
> 515             if self._sampler_iter is None:
> 516                 self._reset()
> --> 517             data = self._next_data()
> 518             self._num_yielded += 1
> 519             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
>
> D:\bo\envs\bd\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in
> _next_data(self)
> 555     def _next_data(self):
> 556         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
> --> 557         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
> 558         if self._pin_memory:
> 559             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)
>
> D:\bo\envs\bd\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py in
> fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
> 45         else:
> 46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
> ---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26192/2257937436.py in
> sparse_batch_collate(batch)
> 67         data_batch = sparse_coo_to_tensor(data_batch)
> 68     else:
> ---> 69         data_batch = torch.FloatTensor(data_batch)
> 70
> 71     if type(targets_batch[0]) == csr_matrix:
>
> TypeError: must be real number, not coo_matrix

**What I have tried**

I have converted each X_i to torch tensor type:

```
def csr2Tensor(csr_data):
    coo_data = csr_data.tocoo()
    return torch.sparse.LongTensor(torch.LongTensor([coo_data.row.tolist(), coo_data.col.tolist()]),
                          torch.LongTensor(coo_data.data.astype(np.int32)))

X_train = [(csr2Tensor(X_train[i]), y_train[i]) for i in range(len(X_train))]
```

Now each X_i is a tuple consisting of a torch tensor looking like:

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[    0,     0,     0,     0,     1,     1,     2,     2,
                            2,     3,     4,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,
                            8,     8,     8,     8,     8,     8,     8,     8,
                            8,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
                            0,     0,     0,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,
                            1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     2,     2,     2,
                            2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     3,
                            3,     3,     3,     3,     3,     3,     3,     3,
                            3,     4,     4,     4,     4,     4,     4,     4,
                            4,     4,     4,     5,     5,     5,     5,     5,
                            5,     5,     5,     5,     5,     6,     6,     6,
                            6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     6,     7,
                            7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,     7,
                            7,     8,     8,     8,     8,     8,     8,     8,
                            8,     8,     8],
                       [ 1738,  1740,  3404,  3405,  9545, 12467, 12458, 12464,
                        12492,  9226, 12440, 12492,  9552, 12440,  9226,  9671,
                         9967, 10011, 10392, 10394, 10424, 10454, 10560, 11757,
                        13176, 15465, 15464, 15457, 15453, 15448, 15445, 15437,
                        15436, 15431, 15427, 15465, 15464, 15457, 15453, 15448,
                        15445, 15437, 15436, 15431, 15427, 15465, 15464, 15457,
                        15453, 15448, 15445, 15437, 15436, 15431, 15427, 15465,
                        15464, 15457, 15453, 15448, 15445, 15437, 15436, 15431,
                        15427, 15465, 15464, 15457, 15453, 15448, 15445, 15437,
                        15436, 15431, 15427, 15465, 15464, 15457, 15453, 15448,
                        15445, 15437, 15436, 15431, 15427, 15465, 15464, 15457,
                        15453, 15448, 15445, 15437, 15436, 15431, 15427, 15465,
                        15464, 15457, 15453, 15448, 15445, 15437, 15436, 15431,
                        15427, 15465, 15464, 15457, 15453, 15448, 15445, 15437,
                        15436, 15431, 15427]]),
       values=tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1]),
       size=(9, 15466), nnz=115, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

And now I am having

> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26192/2257937436.py in
> sparse_batch_collate(batch)
> 67         data_batch = sparse_coo_to_tensor(data_batch)
> 68     else:
> ---> 69         data_batch = torch.FloatTensor(data_batch)
> 70
> 71     if type(targets_batch[0]) == csr_matrix:
>
> ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python
> scalars

If I use a simple custom dataset class instead of the sparse one. When I start the training of an Attention() model, I get a `TypeError: expected CPU (got SparseCPU)` error. Now I am confused about what to do. Any advice and help are appreciated!